# Can quantum particle wave functions be located on multiple points in space at once?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, wavefunction

When physicists say that a quantum particle's position is uncertain, does that mean specifically that the location where the wave function may collapse on a detector is uncertain?

Or can a wave function itself be centred on multiple points in space at once?

Comment: It is *extremely* rare for 'quantum' to appear as a substantive, and if so, it is generally only as part of "a quantum of energy", which is a rather hand-wavy description of other processes unrelated to your question. Presumably you mean "a quantum particle" instead.

Comment: What do you mean by centered?  Sometimes the trick to these questions is just in the wording.  You can create what are called "bimodal" distributions where the probability density function has multiple peaks.

Comment: Both? A wavefunction can be (and it usually is) delocalised in space, which implies the uncertainty in the location where it will collapse if measured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When physicists say that a quantum particle's position is uncertain, does that mean specifically that the location where the wave function may collapse on a detector is uncertain?

Not only the location, but also that our mathematical wavefunction  models do not predict a specific location for a particle in the quantum mechanical frame of the microcosm. As a rule of thumb there is the [Heisenberg Uncertainty principle, HUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle).

For the space variables it has to obey $\Delta x \Delta p \geq \hbar/2$ where p is the momentum . So defining an $x$ point in the wavefunction constraints to momentum, introducing a fuzziness, which has been validated with measurements in experiments.

> Or can a wave function itself be centred on multiple points in space at once?

It is not clear what you mean, a wave function $\Psi(x,y,z,t)$ is mathematically completely defined for a specific boundary condition problem. Its modulus squared will give the *probability* for finding the particle at a specific $(x,y,z,t)$ when measured.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my initial wording of the question, I avoided the term "particle" because it implies a different question than what I am asking (and anyone who has seen an antenna knows they are not for catching particles). I follow Art Hobson's interpretation that the uncertainty principle does not describe a "particle" having uncertain location in space, but the uncertainty of where a wave will interact with a detector. 

My real question is the second part, & I think you have answered it. To confirm, the extent of a wave-function in space cannot itself be uncertain.

Comment: Yes , the wavefunction is a completely defined function in space and time by the imposition of boundary conditions to the solutions of the equation.